# How to connect my facebook page with my app

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am having a trouble. I am currently in my final yrs in college and we are developing an application using flutter. Our client already got an website and Facebook page what they are asking us is to connect their Facebook page , Website with their new app. For example they they are saying that if they update anything in the application then that should be updated in the website and Facebook  page also. So we are stuck over here. How to solve this is there any link to article so research on ?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the website, you need same database which is being used on the web. For example, if you add some information using your app, it will make changes in your website also. About the Facebook part, Can you be more specific what are you trying to do with Facebook page?

Comment: Ok Thanks for the information. On the part of Facebook page. The organization has got a facebook page where they use to update about their services what they are saying to us is that they want the facebook page to be updated with the post once they update that on application. Is it even possible ?

Comment: I don't think that is possible because Facebook doesn't provide anything that we can control its page using our app. May be it will happen in some time

Answer (score 1):

Facebook provides read only permission to the users while for extra features that you want like update page, post , delete and many more . You have to send request to facebook submitting your application where one API call should be there and testing from outside should be done.
[Facebook normal permission available to use without sending request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgVGC.png)